# Parsing a json object with fields in different orders for redshift copy

Tags: python, json

Needing to parse a json object in lambda using python so that a redshift copy command can be executed and load data.

Below is an example of the json object generated from a query string where the ordering is different depending on factors.

```
{"person":..., "address":...,"state":...},
{"person":..., "address":...,"state":...},
{"address":..., "state":...,"person":...},
```

The issue right now that I have is that I have operations to format the json in a way that redshift will accept the format. For every new json object, i need to remove the comma. From the above example, post format would look like

```
{"person":..., "address":...,"state":...}{"address":..., "state":...,"person":...}
```

logic for the process is `res = res.replace(',{"person"' , '}{"person"')`
With the above logic for objects with different ordering `{"address":..., "state":...,"person":...}` this becomes a problem. As the assumption is that `{"person"` is always the first field which is not entirely true.

Also tried converting the json to csv, but that becomes a problem with data doesn't align with the column name.

Comment: What does this have to do with lambdas? Maybe you mean AWS Lambda, but I don't see how that's relevant to the problem -- not that I've used it myself.

Comment: Have you considered something like `''.join(json.dumps(obj) for obj in obj_list)`? Although, it's not clear if you're ever parsing the JSON to Python data or just leaving it as a string. It'd help if you made a [mre]. For more tips, like how to write a good title, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

#### If there is no nesting, it is easy

What I mean is, if the only `{` and `}` characters are the ones you have shown, the replacement command can just look for those.

```
res = res.replace(
    "},{",
    "}{"
)
```

#### If there is nesting, it's more difficult

You can't rely on `},{` alone to detect the need for replacement.

As long as the field names at this level are not found at any other level, you could try this:

```
field_names = ["person", "address", "state"]
for field_name in field_names:
        res = res.replace(
          '},{"'+field_name+'"',
          '}{"'+field_name+'"',
        )
```